# Action cable client for android

Tags: android, actioncable

I want to subscribe to a specific channel of action cable.
Any library or client of actioncable for android?
I am using one library https://github.com/hosopy/actioncable-client-java but not able to connect with action cable.

Comment: Did you check if the issue is not the library but something else such as lack of credentials to access, server down, or anything else that would prevent the library to reach and interact the endpoint?

Comment: @acarlstein server is up and running,

Answer (score 0):

1.connect with the rails action cable path

```
private void start() {
        try {
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://"+Constants.HOST_ADDRESS +"/cable").addHeader("auth-token", AUTH_TOKEN).build();
            EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
            WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
            client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
            client = new OkHttpClient();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2.Subscribe to the channel

```
private final class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            webSocket.send("{\"command\":\"subscribe\", \"identifier\":\"{\\\"channel\\\":\\\"CommunicationsChannel\\\"}\"}");
        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonBot = new JSONObject(text);
                }
        }
}
```

The WebSocket listener can receive all the message send from rails application via ‘CommunicationsChannel’, you will be able to recive it in ‘onMessage’ function

check this resource for other actionable android implementation :

https://www.xploralab.com/?s=action+cable